# top N allow duplicates algorithm for distributed data

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, language-agnostic, distributed-computing

Difference between top N and top N allow duplicates:

```
input: 1, 9, 7, 9, 5, 10, 7
top 3: 10, 9, 9
top 3 allow duplicates: 10, 9, 9, 7, 7
```

The top N distributed algorithm is intuitive. All machines runs a top N algorithm and one machine getter all the results together and run a top N algorithm.

```
machine A: 1,9, 
machine B: 9, 5,10, 7, 7

step 1: each machine runs top 3
machine A: 9, 1
machine B: 10, 9, 7

step 2: machine C get all results and runs top N 
input to machine C: 9, 1, 10, 9, 7
run top 3 again: 10, 9, 9
```

Top N algorithm runs on each machine could implement using heap and the time complexity will be O(MlogN) (M=# of input rows)

Top N allow duplicate could apply similar distribute algorithm, but I don’t know how to prove it. and I cannot think of a counter example.

```
machine A: 1,9
machine B: 9, 5,10, 7, 7

step 1: each machine runs top 3 allow duplicates
machine A: 9, 1
machine B: 10, 9, 7, 7

step 2: machine C get all results and runs top N allow duplicates 
input to machine C: 9, 1, 10, 9, 7, 7
run top 3 again: 10, 9, 9,7,7
```

Top N allow duplicate runs on each machine could implement using heap + map(in order to dedup) and the time complexity will also be O(MlogN) (M=# of input rows)

How to prove this is correct? Or what’s the counter example to prove its incorrect?

Comment: To support correctness, you must first analyze the algorithm.  To do that, you must *specify* the algorithm.  You've loosely described a couple of approaches, but haven't actually detailed the algorithms in use.  For one thing, you haven't described your partitioning.

Comment: Assuming that you partition your data into `i` equal sets, and then run your base algorithm on each partition, then the recombination is simple: it's combining `i` result sets of `N` items with duplicates.  The original job is now **O([M/i] log N)**; you have to combine `i` result sets, each of which can be the entire set of data.  How does that scale?

Comment: @Prune. We have a user case for top N allow duplicates and current implementation is just aggregate all data to a single machine and sort. The listed solution don't have constant networking IO, but it's still better than a global sorting. But I need to prove the correctness.